# How to sort files by an specific order

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to sort the files I'm saving according to their creation / last modification time.
It turns out that the files are generated so quickly that their creation date ends up being the same.

For example, let's say I have an array of objects:

```
data = [
      { "Name": "Kevin Durant", "Team": "Brooklyn Nets" },
      { "Name": "LeBron James", "Team": "Los Angeles Lakers" },
      { "Name": "Trae Young", "Team": "Atlanta Hawks" },
];
```

I create a directory:

```
download_folder = os.path.expanduser("~")+"/Downloads/"
dir_name = "NBA"
makedir_path = os.path.join(download_folder, dir_name)
if not os.path.exists(makedir_path):
    os.makedirs(makedir_path)
```

I use a for to save each object in a different file (the name of each file will be the name of the player's team):

```
for document in data:
  file_name = document["Team"] + ".txt"
  path = os.path.join(makedir_path, file_name)
  open(path, "x")    
  with open(os.path.join(makedir_path, file_name),'w') as new_f:
      json.dump(found_database, new_f, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

After creating the files, I try to order them according to the creation / modification date (which would be the same order as the elements of the array of object):

```
os.chdir(makedir_path)
files = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(makedir_path))
files = [os.path.join(makedir_path, f) for f in files]
files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))
# Another way I tried to order but it didn't work
# files.sort(key=os.path.getctime)
```

But, instead, the files are ordered by the file name (team name):

[image]

I want it to be ordered by the same array order. So I would have this:

```
Brooklyn Nets.txt
Los Angeles Lakers.txt
Atlanta Hawks.txt
```

Is that even possible, or the OS itself sorts it by its name by default? Thank you!

Comment: The OS doesn't sort the files. The client that displays the list of files (Windows Explorer in this case) sorts the viewed list. Windows Explorer offers various 'sort by' options so you can sort by last modified data, among other attributes.

Comment: @jarmod I know that, I want to know if it is possible to order the list of files directly from the code using the array order

Comment: Store the file names in a list, populated in the order you want them, then later you can use list.index(filename) as your custom sort lambda key.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think there is anything you can easily do with your OS for that.

However, I can propose based on your array:

```
import glob
import os

data = [
          { "Name": "Kevin Durant", "Team": "Brooklyn Nets" },
          { "Name": "LeBron James", "Team": "Los Angeles Lakers" },
          { "Name": "Trae Young", "Team": "Atlanta Hawks" },
       ]

for filename in glob.glob("*txt"):
    name = filename.split(".")[0]
    for i, dat in enumerate(data):
        if dat['Team'] == name:
            os.rename(filename,str(i)+"_"+filename.replace(" ","_"))
            print (str(i)+"_"+filename.replace(" ","_"))
```

Then you'll have a numerical ID that corresponds to your list for each file.